# What is the pattern in the ship names in the Interdependency series?

Tags: reference, the-interdependency

The names seem peculiar.
I feel like they are referencing something.

- "Yes, Sir, That’s My Baby"

  - this is a Frank Sinatra song
- "No, Sir, I Don’t Mean Maybe"

  - the second line from the Frank Sinatra song
- "I'll always remember you like a child"

  - this is a line from the song Wild World by Cat Stevens
- "If You Want to Sing Out, Sing Out"

  - this is the title of a different song by Cat Stevens

I don't recognise:

- "Tell me another one"
- "Toun Sandin"
- "Oliveer Bransid"
- "Red Rose"

Or any of the other ships named.
Are a the ship names song references?

Comment: They always reminded me of race horse names.

Comment: I think we can only really comment on the naming pattern of a particular house; the first 2 are House Lagos, while *Child* is Nohamapetan.  Most houses could reasonably be expected to have their own naming schemes.

Answer (score 6):

John Scalzi is on record (on twitter at least) as saying that his ship names in the Interdependency series are a homage to the ship names of Iain M. Banks: https://twitter.com/scalzi/status/1267433885769629696?lang=en

> I'm seeing a lot of comments like this, re: the SpaceX ship name. I'm pretty sure the inspiration is from Iain M. Banks' culture series, in no small part because *my* ship names in the Interdependency series are a tip of the hat to Banks, of whom I am a fan.

This means they can be a mixture of sarcasm, common sayings, lyrics and modified versions of these too - as well as more serious or descriptive (*). In an interview (https://www.theguardian.com/books/2000/sep/11/iainbanks-science-fiction) Banks revealed the in-universe reason behind the "Gravitas" series of ship names (also picked up by SpaceX) that other civilisations were annoyed by the Culture's sarcastic and flippant attitude to naming ships:

> ... it was a scathing review of Culture ship-naming policy delivered by another Involved civilisation. They suggested that such enormously powerful and intellectually refined entities ought to have names with a little more gravitas, to reflect their near-god-like status; the immediate and sustained reaction of one of the Culture's ship manufacturies was to name all its subsequent vessels things like: Stood Far Back When The Gravitas Was Handed Out; Gravitas, What Gravitas?; Gravitas... Gravitas... No, Don't Help Me, I'll Get It In A Moment; Gravitas Free Zone; Low Gravitas Warning Signal, etc etc (including the Zen-like Absolutely No You-No-What). I am so sad I have a separate list of the Gravitas ships at home. It currently runs to about 20, I think.

(*) - in one of the books there is a comment by a character that the warships tend to have simpler, more descriptive and blunter names. If I can remember which one, I will add it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the names here and some others, it seems to be very different from house to house

The "Yes sir, that's my baby" and "No sir, I don't mean maybe" are both from house Lagos, and so Frank Sinatra seems to be the theme of house Lagos

The "I'll always remember you like a child" and "If you want to sing out, sing out" are House Nohamapetan, which means their theme is Cat Stevens

The others are likely just more conventional ship names based on the theme of the house they're from.

"Tell me another one" is a British saying, so that may be a theme.

"Red rose" references flowers, so another house may have a floral theme

For the other two, I have no idea.

Comment: Those last two look like puns. Toun Sandin looks like pun on Townsend. "Oliveer Bransid" - Johnathan Brandis had a role in "Oliver and Company" film. But it might also be a pun on "Olive, er, branch,s, I'd (Yes, I would)" . Maybe.